# User permissions needed to run subprocess in Python under Nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, django, nginx, subprocess, uwsgi

[EDIT: The bug was not in the permissions.  I had not provided a full path to the db in settings.py (using SQLITE3), so uwsgi could not find it. Thanks to @spicavigo for the guidance!]

I have a simple Django app running on a Linux (Ubuntu) server, served by nginx and uwsgi.  The application takes an uploaded document from the user and runs a local executable through subprocess.call, to convert the document from pdf to text.

`subprocess.call(['pdftotext', pdffilepath], shell = True)`

This subprocess call is not working, and I get an error related to the permissions on the folder where the uploaded document is stored ('media/').

I've set the owner of the path to the app, and the media folder, as www-data, which is also the user for nginx and uwsgi.  I've also set all of these to ubuntu.  Still no luck.  The app works fine under the Django server (`python manage.py runserver`).

Thoughts on what I need to do or where I went wrong in my settings?

Comment: Hey Ari, could you do a ls -ltr of the folder that contains media/ and paste it here

Comment: Having the same issue, Ari did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: In my case (as I noted in the edit to my question) I had an error in the settings.py file; I needed to provide the full path to the database. Assuming your app works with the Django server, but not in production, there may be an incorrect setting.